# piping echo and cat doesn’t works

Tags: bash

I'm coding a script that installs firmware for a server.
I have stuck in args for output versions from XML files in the terminal.

```
echo "BROADCOM NIC Version : " | cat firmware-nic-broadcom-*/CP*.xml | grep "<Version>" | uniq | sed 's/[^0-9,.]//g'
```

I want to output "BROADCOM NIC Version : 20.19.31", but it just shows "20.19.31".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
echo -n "BROADCOM NIC Version : " ; cat firmware-nic-broadcom-*/CP*.xml | grep "<Version>" | uniq | sed 's/[^0-9,.]//g'
     ^^ Add                       ^ Change
```

The `-n` flag says echo with no new line, and changing the `|` to a `;` means that it always outputs directly rather than getting lost in the piping.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare VERSION variable first.

```
VERSION=$(cat firmware-nic-broadcom-*/CP*.xml | grep "<Version>" | uniq | sed 's/[^0-9,.]//g')
echo "BROADCOM NIC Version : ${VERSION}"
```